# How to use Fixedsys in the Gnome Terminal, or wherever monospaced fonts are required

Tags: fonts, gnome-terminal, .ttf

I think that the [Fixedsys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixedsys) font is one of the most legible monospaced fonts for programming. It has zero antialiasing, with vertical lines mostly 2 pixels wide. Close to ideal for current monitor dot pitches, in my eyes (literally). Here is a sample:

[image: Fixedsys sample]

After years of Windows at home (for family reasons) and Linux servers at work accessed through Cygwin on Windows (for company policy reasons), with Fixedsys as the shell and IDE font, I have finally decided to switch to Ubuntu at home.

Eclipse and gedit are no problem, they accept a corrected version of the [Fixedsys Excelsior](http://www.fixedsysexcelsior.com/) TTF font that you can find [here at comment #16](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/200671) (filename: FSEX301-L2.ttf). But the Gnome Terminal only accepts monospaced fonts.

Although Fixedsys Excelsior is essentially monospaced, it contains larger glyphs (mostly for eastern languages), and also some ligatures. Since apparently ALL characters must have the same width for a font to be recognized as monospaced, Fixedsys Excelsior cannot be selected in all those contexts where monospaced fonts are required, including gnome-terminal.

So what is the easiest/cleanest way to use a Fixedsys clone in contexts that only accept monospaced fonts?

Comment: BTW, to use Fixedsys Excelsior in NetBeans, you have to add `-J-Dswing.aatext=false` to netbeans_default_options in /etc/netbeans.conf . Otherwise NetBeans will render it "colored" and blurry - this applies to Windows too

Comment: Update to my previous comment: Netbeans 7.4 on Windows requires `-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on` to get rid of the anti-aliasing.

Comment: On the MacBook Pro I have to work with the sample image is not sharp. The Fixedsys font appears to have grey border pixels. AFAICT this is because of the so-called "retina" display, a high resolution display which causes images within HTML to be scaled by a factor of two (yes, they preferred to break HTML and to have blurred images...). The same scaling applies to the font itself, spoiling it. On the other hand, high resolution displays greatly enhance the legibility off all fonts, obviating the need of Fixedsys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the solution I found. I have tested it thoroughly several times, and I have been using the resulting font in a number of places for over 2 years now, but be warned: some parts of the procedure may be anywhere from suboptimal to plain wrong.

Before you ask "why don't you make the resulting font available", the answer is: "because I'm not sure I can do so". Font copyright is an intricate matter.

---

Download the [corrected Fixedsys Excelsior font](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/200671) (file `FSEX301-L2.ttf`, at comment #16)

Install [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/) (e.g., from the Ubuntu Software Center)

Right-click on the `FSEX301-L2.ttf` file and open it with FontForge. In the *Load Bitmap Fonts* window that appears, click on **No**.

Click on **File → Execute Script...**, and copy&paste the following into the window that appears:

```
SelectAll()
foreach
   if (GlyphInfo("Width") != 80)
      DetachAndRemoveGlyphs()
   else
      b = GlyphInfo("BBox")
      if (b[0] < 0 || b[1] < -30 || b[2] > 80 || b[3] > 130)
         DetachAndRemoveGlyphs()
      endif
   endif
endloop
SelectNone()
```

Then select **FF** and click **OK** (it will take a while, you will have to wait until the *Execute Script* window disappears)

Click **Element → Font Info...** In **PS Names** change the **Fontname**, **Family Name**, and **Name for Humans**, e.g., by appending `Mono` (spaces are allowed only in the second and third string).

In the same *Font Information* window, select **OS/2**.
In the **Misc.** tab change the **PFM Family** to **Monospace**.
<strike>In the Metrics tab, set Win Descent Offset and HHead Descent Offset both to 0</strike> <sup>(*)</sup>.
In the **Panose** tab, change **Proportion** to **Monospaced**.

In the same *Font Information* window, select **Lookups**.
In the **GSUB** tab, and in the **GPOS** tab, select each line in turn and click **Delete**.

In the same *Font Information* window, click **OK**, and in the *Change UniqueID?* window that appears click **Change**.

If you want, you can tweak one or more questionable features of Fixedsys. E.g., the zero character is shifted one pixel to the right. To shift it back to center, double click on it, then click **Metrics → Set LBearing...**, set the **LBearing** to `10` and click **OK**. You can also change the shape of characters, but always keep control points at multiples of 10, and the width at 80.

Click **Element → Bitmap Strikes Available...**, then, in the window that appears set **Pixel Sizes** to `16` and click **OK**.

Click **File → Generate Fonts...**, choose a different directory and/or a different filename if needed, make sure the output format is **TrueType**, and click **Save**. In the *Non-standard Em-Size* window that appears click **Yes**. In the *Errors detected* window that appears next click **Save** (don't worry).

Quit FontForge (**File → Quit**). In the *Font changed* window that appears click **Don't Save**.

---

Move the generated file to the `.fonts` subdirectory of your home directory (create it if it doesn't exist).

Open the Gnome Terminal. Click **Edit → Profiles...** In a profile (I suggest you create a new one) change the font to `Fixedsys Excelsior 3.01-L2 Mono` (or whatever you have called the mono version of Fixedsys Excelsior), at size `12` (which is the only "true" Fixedsys size). If you want, you can also disable bold text. I suggest black text on white background, but that is a matter of taste.

The bold variant of this font is equivalent to repeating the character shifted by one pixel to the right (this is different from `FSEX301-L2.ttf`, where it appears smoothed). It is not very legible - but do you really need bold? I don't. The problem is only with those contexts where bold cannot be disabled (not even, e.g., by editing syntax highlighting), especially in those cases where the character spacing is incremented by one pixel as well, breaking alignments (this is not the case in gnome-terminal). I haven't found a solution to this last nuisance yet. Suggestions are welcome.

---

(*): not needed since the FontForge release of 2012-07-31 (in 14.04 LTS - Trusty Tahr)

Comment: To all who have saved and/or applied this recipe: please note that it may have slightly changed in the meanwhile in order to solve some small problems, and that it may still change in the future. You could have a look at the edit history.

Comment: FYI, works fine on Windows, too. Also with "Fixedsys Excelsior 2.0" (which, in my opinion, is much better for terminals since the characters are a bit less high than in FSEX3). Great font for PuTTY! (the original FSEX and any font that is considered non-monospace makes PuTTY *really* slow when the screen refreshes very often)

Comment: PhpStorm 7.1 on 14.04 does not recognize the font I describe in my answer as being a monospaced font, I don't know why :-( Luckily, if you uncheck "show only monospaced fonts", you can still get it. For some reason the size must be either 15 or 16 (they look the same) instead of 12. PhpStorm seems to be a bit buggy to me...

Answer (score 3):

Great solution by Walter Tross, but if you don't want to do all the job, here is the download link:

[FixedsysExcelsiorIIIb-L2_Mono.ttf](https://mega.nz/#!V9JTXKZJ!48OPvvFTR-dRI94AecWBoJAGOSGC-31UnIV2TpV45NU)

Comment: Thanks Rafael, the "why" is in the second paragraph of my answer

Comment: Ops! Sorry... Lack of attention... Fixed now.